# Limit access to certain Facebook photo albums

Tags: facebook, privacy, facebook-photos

I know it is possible to define groups of friends. But how do I allow/exclude groups to see a photo-album? Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a list of the friends that you want to be able to include or exclude for your album.

Then you need to :

- Edit your album
- In the Privacy drop down select `Customize`
- Then in the These people drop down select `Specific people`
- Your friend list should appear as you type.

When I tested this initially my friend list did not appear but as it turns out you can add friend lists to the privacy settings.

You should be aware that is a friend is a member of two lists the most restrictive permissions are applied to your friend.

Further information on Friend Lists can be found [here](http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=15705)